# dmarc result in the case of Spf Temperror and Dkim fail

Tags: spf, dmarc

I can't figure out what should be dmarc result if:

1. Dkim fail
2. AND Spf Temperror
3. AND Spf alignment MISmatch

"Fail" or "Unknown"

RFC 7489 (Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance (DMARC)) doesn't explain this clearly enough for me:

`DMARC evaluation can only yield a "pass" result after one of the underlying authentication mechanisms passes for an aligned identifier.  If neither passes and one or both of them fail due to a temporary error, the Receiver evaluating the message is unable to conclude that the DMARC mechanism had a permanent failure; they therefore cannot apply the advertised DMARC policy.  When otherwise appropriate, Receivers MAY send feedback reports regarding temporary errors.`

From the other side, Spf alignment is important.
For example,

1. DKIM=fail, Spf=pass, spf no alignment => DMARC will give "Fail"
2. DKIM=fail, Spf=Temperror, spf no alignment => DMARC will give "Fail" or "Enable to conclude"?

Comment: Consider asking this question on webmasters.stackexchange.com and not on SO

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate for Serverfault rather than here.